# no answers, no users, on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, site-stats

Why does the [site overview](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) claim 0 answers, 0 users for Stack Overflow?

[image: site overview]

Comment: Too many complaints, we had to shut it down, sorry!

Comment: On the plus side, 100% answer rate!

Comment: 3.9m questions, 0 answers, but still 100% answersed! Also peculiar: SmugMug has existed for 282 days, has 330 questions (including 11 in the last 5 days) but is listed as 0.1 questions/day

Comment: @gerrit Just wait for the developers to ask on SO what might cause their problem while pasting a huge slab of code.

Comment: @gerrit: I believe that a 7-day rolling average, not an average for the life of the site.  [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/25069/smugmug) shows the same rate.

Comment: @JonEricson ah, the 11/5 was the 'active' tab, not 'newest'. The 0.1 q/day is correct...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We picked up some bad data from [APIv2](http://api.stackexchange.com/) and cached it for a short while. I'm temporarily blaming all minor weirdness such as this on our [new Oregon hardware](http://blog.serverfault.com/2012/10/30/failing-over-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange-for-sandy/) :)

The zeros have fallen out of cache (and we also just deployed updated caching logic), so it's fixed now.