# THE SITES, ZAY ARE FAILINK!

Tags: bug, status-completed, question-lists

There seems to be some performance issues going on - the active tabs/main pages are empty, things are intermittently loading and not loading, and.. well.. the sites arn't running like clockwork like they usually do. I'm seeing blank front pages here, SU, SF and on Ask Ubuntu at least.

I'm aware of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153456/no-answers-no-users-on-stack-overflow) but the issue seems different, more widespread and the other one is fixed, so it can't be the same bug, can it?

EDIT: Apparently SE has version numbers! Mine say `rev 2012.11.2.271` If a site's non worky might help to check that. It seems to be working for me now

Screenshot:

[image: Ask Ubuntu is empty!]

[image: Betas are empty]

Comment: Just saw this on Ask Ubuntu on the default home page (both logged in and not).

Comment: Looks like there's some serious problem since 10 minutes now!

Comment: Front pages looked empty on Bicycles, RaspberryPi, and Meta.SO.  But they seem to be working now. Edit, looks like they are failing again.

Comment: Now there's exactly 1 question on Ask Ubuntu! Edit: It vanished!

Comment: Hold me, I'm scared.

Comment: Where's the "Alert sysadmin" red button ??

Comment: @Remou: I think that's an irrelevant bug, also might happen just to you.

Comment: @Remou Came up fine for me in Chrome.

Comment: Who want's to bet it's related to daylight savings time? Just a day early.

Comment: @Kibbee It's fall behind, spring ahead, symlink `/etc/localtime` Damn this is confusing.

Comment: Just loaded fine for me.

Comment: Seems back up at the moment, but since I've seen it go down --> up --> down --> up we'll have to see if it stays up...

Comment: Funny, opened up meta earlier to see if this had already been reported and it was happening here too.

Comment: Everything is working for me now.

Comment: This is part of the GREAT QUESTION CLEANUP OF 2012

Comment: @Pekka All the arguments about close voting, bad migrations,  what's "constructive" -- they finally found the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This usually means the tag engine is misbehaving, but everything's looking good at the moment.

Holler if it breaks again.

Comment: Slightly disconcerting that a misbehaving *tag* engine would prevent any *questions* from being displayed (as opposed to the, you know, *tags*)...

Comment: @Aarobot When a Diesel engine is misbehaving, that doesn't mean there's no Diesel. It just means it doesn't help you much :)

Comment: **It broke again!**

Comment: Ask Ubuntu seems to be working on refresh.

Answer (score 11):

In the mean time, if you really like to get to answer questions, append `/?tab=interesting` to the domain which will use the Stack Overflow approach to filling up the default front page, since Stack Overflow uses this different approach it isn't part of the breakage.

Another approach is to keep the front page open and let the live updates fill it over time.